# Install maven 3.1.1 plugin for eclipse juno

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

I want to install maven 3.1.1 for eclipse.
I use Eclipse MarketPlace to find maven. After installing, I check the version of maven is 3.0.4. How can I install the maven with version 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install Maven separately, and then link your Eclipse installation to it. I've made it work with Eclipse Kepler, but it should work with Juno as well. Here's the instructions to install and configure maven 3.1
[Installing Maven](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven)

Comment: Can you please give more instructions about how to link Eclipse to the maven installation?